# Which on is the the correct form:"Let’s to take" or "Let’s take"

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm studying an educational English common sentences flash card set and it is supposed to be correct! and I find this sentence there: "The main road is blocked. Let’s to take the byroad."

which on is the the correct form:

> The main road is blocked. Let’s to take the byroad.
>
> The main road is blocked. Let’s take the byroad.

Comment: Any prior research.  Have you seen any examples of this form in textbook, or heard anyone ever using the "let's" construction?

Comment: I'm studying an educational English common sentences flash card set and it is supposed to be correct! and i find this sentence there:
"The main road is blocked. Let’s to take the byroad."
This is why i asked it here!
maybe i should change my resources.

Comment: Please add that to the question!  It's really important to include this kind of context.  I'll do it this time.

Comment: @JamesK Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Let's" construction always takes a bare infinitive.

> Let's eat!
>
> Let's take the byroad.
>
> Let's be friends.